# Is there any mathematical results that quantifies the error that a deep-learning network does while approximating a function?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, svm, artificial-intelligence

I am working with kernel methods (AKA Support Vector Machines), and found that they outperform systematically deep-learning methods, in all the numerical experiments I have done. Indeed, I noticed that deep-learning methods seems to provide non converging methods. So I was wondering if there exists any mathematical results stating that deep-learning approach can approximate a simple, one dimensional function ?
Such results are straightforward with kernel methods, but I did not find any usable mathematical results for deep learning. Is there exists any ?

Note : the [Universal Approximation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) or Cybenko approach are not useful here.

Comment: Why doesn’t the universal approximation theorem come into play?

Comment: Because the UAT is silent regarding convergence rate. Let me develop this argument : the UAT simply states that a continous function can be approximated arbitrarily well by a network. It does not tell you how many operations your computer must do to reach a given error level.